# Irreducible representation of $\mathcal{S}_5$ over $\mathbb{C}$ of degree 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, permutations

I have come to a point where I need an irreducible representation of $\mathcal{S}_5$ over $\mathbb{C}$ of degree 4.

Can somebody help me to find one and explain how to obtain one?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the permutation representation $V$ obtained by the usual action of $S_5$ on a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_5$ for $\mathbb C^5$.
This representation has one obvious invariant subspace, namely the diagonal 
$$
\Delta : e_1 = e_2 = e_3 = e_4 = e_5 .
$$
The 4 dimensional complement $W$ of $\Delta$ is defined by $\sum e_i = 0$.
To get an explicit representation of $W$ in terms of matrices, you could use the convenient basis $\{e_i - e_{i+1} : 1 \leq i \leq 4 \}$.

To see that $W$ is irreducible, you can check to see if the character of $W$ has inner product 1 with itself.
Once you have an explicit representation of $W$ in terms of matrices, you can calculate this character by hand.
Alternately, note that the character $\chi$ of $V$ is given by 
$$
  \chi(g) = |\{x : gx = x\}|,
$$
and the character of $W$ is $\chi - 1$.

Whenever you have a group acting doubly transitively on a set of size $n$, this same process will result in an irreducible representation of degree $n-1$.
For a proof of this fact, see these [notes](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind2_6.html).

*Edit:* 
Let $\phi\colon S_5 \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ be the 4 dimensional representation described above.
To compute $\phi$ explicitly, let's choose the basis
$$
  b_i = e_i - e_{i+1}, \quad i=1,2,3,4
$$
for $W$.
Then the element $\sigma = (12345)$ acts on this basis like this:
\begin{align*}
  \sigma(b_1) &= e_2 - e_3 = b_2 \\
  \sigma(b_2) &= e_3 - e_4 = b_3 \\
  \sigma(b_3) &= e_4 - e_5 = b_4 \\
  \sigma(b_4) &= e_5 - e_1 = -(b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4) .
\end{align*}
The element $\tau = (12)$ acts like this:
\begin{align*}
  \sigma(b_1) &= e_2 - e_1 = -b_1  \\
  \sigma(b_2) &= e_1 - e_3 = b_1 + b_2 \\
  \sigma(b_3) &= e_3 - e_4 = b_3 \\
  \sigma(b_4) &= e_4 - e_5 = b_4 .
\end{align*}
Therefore, with respect to the basis $b_i$, we have
$$
  \phi(\sigma) 
  = \begin{pmatrix} 
  0&0&0&-1\\
  1&0&0&-1\\
  0&1&0&-1\\
  0&0&1&-1
  \end{pmatrix} ,
  \qquad
  \phi(\tau)
  = \begin{pmatrix} 
  -1&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&1
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
Since $\sigma,\tau$ generate all of $S_5$, you can get the rest of the $\phi(g), g \in S_5$ from these.

Comment: I understand all your explanation, but it's not clear to me how to get an explicit representation. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Loes Sure. See my edit.